# Spring @RepositoryRestController causes @PageableDefault to stop working

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a custom controller that is using the @PageableDefault annotation. I was using @Controller annotation on my class, however, I wanted to make this controller respond with the HATEOAS response. I added the @RepositoryRestController changed my method to

```java
public HttpEntity<PagedResources<Resource<Books>>> search(
                      @RequestParam(value = "q", required = false) String query,
                      @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 20) Pageable pageable)
```

and then the return to

```java
return new ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Resource<Books>>> booksAssembler
                                               .toResource(queryResult), HttpStatus.OK);
```

Now my @PageableDefault doesn't work. But when a client make a request (e.g. explicitly adding (or without) &page=0&size=20 to the URL) the endpoint from the controller, pageable is always null. I don't get why it stop working after changing the annotation? Is there any way to fix it other than changing back to @Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I was running into this bug. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-906

I was using Spring Boot 1.4.1, upgrading to 1.4.2 solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across `@PageableDefault` and is wondering why it is null (and thus doesn't work). Check whether you're also using `@RequestParam` for the same attribute; if you do, remove it.

So, this:

```java
@GetMapping(produces = { MimeTypes.HALJSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
ResponseEntity<PagedModel<EntityModel<Thing>>> getAllThings(
        @PageableDefault(size = 20, sort = { "name" })
        @RequestParam(name = "pageable", required = false) final Pageable pageable) {
        ...
}
```

becomes this:

```java
@GetMapping(produces = { MimeTypes.HALJSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
ResponseEntity<PagedModel<EntityModel<Thing>>> getAllThings(
        @PageableDefault(size = 20, sort = { "name" }) final Pageable pageable) {
        ...
}
```